# How to make text in `NSView` subview `QLPreviewView` selectable?

Tags: cocoa, quicklook, selectable

In 10.7 Lion Apple introduced `QLPreviewView` to allow you to embed quicklook views inside your own app. However, it doesn't seem to allow text selection by default. I found a tip allows you to make the global quicklook preview selectable on macworld, (http://www.macworld.com/article/1164668/select_and_copy_text_within_quick_look_previews.html), but what I really want to be able to do is to make enbedded preview view selectable. I used class-dump on `QuicklookUI.framework` headers but couldn't find anything useful. Does anyone know how to make embedded `QLPreviewView` text selectable? (as in the following example)

[image]